# what's the order of post_save receiver in django?

Tags: django, signals

You can bind multiple post_save(pre_save, etc) receivers to a class.

Is there a way to specify the ordering of receipt of signals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordering signal in django would be a good feature but unfortunately Django does not support this as mentioned in this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16547) although you can have a close look at [Django Signals and the Observer Design Pattern](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/04/django-signals-and-observer-design.html)  to have better understanding of its pattern & design.