# Specifying order of Django signal receivers

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm sending a signal out and I have two functions (each in their own app) that are receivers for this signal and should be run when this signal is sent. Is there any way of specifying the order in which these receivers are run? I know that by changing the order of INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file I can change when they're registered, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the order of post\_save receiver in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990146/whats-the-order-of-post-save-receiver-in-django)

Comment: [Sort django signal's receivers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64426034/9601060)