# Sort django signal's receivers

Tags: python, django, signals

Django calls receiver methods in its own way. Is there any way that we can sort the receivers of Django signal? I didn't find anything related to it in official Django documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by sort the receivers? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Signals are designed for loose coupling, defining an order would imply to define the listeners and be the opposite of what the design intends.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals

"All of the signal’s receiver functions are called one at a time, in the order they were registered."

Try:

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_1(*args, **kwargs):
    print('RECEIVER 1')

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_2(*args, **kwargs):
    print('RECEIVER 2')

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_3(*args, **kwargs):
    print('RECEIVER 3')
```

Output will be:

```
RECEIVER 1
RECEIVER 2
RECEIVER 3
```

And then mix it up...

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, there isn't any reason to have more than one receiver for the same `signal` and `sender`. It is *possible* but I don't believe it is the right way to approach it and you will not have explicit control over the calling sequence of each.

If, for example, you have a set of duplicate signals (that do different things) like so:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()


@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_2(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User)
def signal_receiver_3(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

That would work but the order of execution isn't explicitly known. However, you could rewrite it to something like this to explicitly state the order of execution:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()


def signal_receiver_1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def signal_receiver_2(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def signal_receiver_3(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=User):
def pre_save_signal_receiver_master(*args, **kwargs):
    signal_receiver_1(*args, **kwargs)
    signal_receiver_2(*args, **kwargs)
    signal_receiver_3(*args, **kwargs)
```