# How to trigger Django Signals in sequence

Tags: django, django-orm, django-signals

I am firing a signal which has 3 different receivers. What I want to do is to update a table `Student` using the signal `update_student` and later on I want to update his enrollment in `update_student_enrollment`.

I want to update Enrollment after the Student has been updated. But my update enrollment receiver is triggering before the student is updated.

### Sending the signal.

```
Signal.send("student_updated", student_id=1, active=active)
```

### Receiver 1

```
@receiver(student_updated)
def update_student(sender, **kwargs):
    Student.objects.update(active=0) # I am setting the student activation to false. For simplicity I am not mentioning the logic which is setting the student to inactive.    
    print("Student Updated!")
```

### Receiver 2

```
@receiver(student_updated)
def update_student_enrollment(sender, **kwargs):
    student=Student.objects.filter(student_id=1)
    if student.active=0:
        StudentEnrollment.objects.filter(student_id=1).update(active=0)
```

Somehow my `Receiver 2` is firing before the `Receiver 1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the order of post\_save receiver in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990146/whats-the-order-of-post-save-receiver-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to explicitly specify the ordering of signals in Django.

The best way you can handle this is by having the Receiver 1 signal send a signal itself on which you can let Receiver 2 listen.